# Where do I sell Specials? Achievement: Aren't you Special

Tags: achievements, farmville-country-escape

How can I sell the specials?

I would like to get the Google Play achievement but my selling board does not have a "special". I am level 52.

I understand I may be lacking some requirements for it.

[image: image of achievement]

Answer (score 1):

Special should be those orders with a golden background:

[image]

You can find them on Farm Orders Board and Pike Orders Board.

Comment: Hey i finally unlocked that board with the 3rd water plot, but  the achievement didn't appear in the game, and I sold all the specials but I didn't get anything

Comment: @achecopar I found a very low quality image saying that, when Pike's returns from fishing, Shrimps (or a random good, I suppose) will go on specials. So it must be something related to Pike. Have you found him?

Comment: He is the one running Pike Orders Board, but I don't see how to get him to go fishing

Comment: However i did get special orders, and i completed 7 of them. The achievement didn't pop up on the game achievement list and google play list still says 0% progress

Comment: Is this thing still a thing? You can't find how to sell specials, I hope they weren't removed from the game

Comment: I did sell 7 specials.